# c# does not recognize eval if

Tags: c#, .net, eval

Data binding methods such as Eval(), XPath() and Bind() can only be used in a data-limited control context.

Explanation: An unhandled exception occurred while executing the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originates in the code.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Data binding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the data-bound control context.

Source Error:

```
Satır 306: </div>
Satır 307: <div class="pl-0 pl-md-4 mt-3 mt-md-0">
Satır 308:     <% if (Eval("services_longtitle").ToString() == "Google Ads Services") { %>
Satır 309:     <p class="h4"><%# Eval ("services_sectiontitle") %></p>
Satır 310:     <% } %>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Comment: *"can only be used in the data-bound control context."* - more context on where that code lies may hold the clue to your peril.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use this code outside of a data-bound control, you might want to consider using it within a control that supports data binding, such as a GridView, Repeater, DataList, etc.

Here's an example using a GridView..

```
<asp:GridView ID="yourGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("services_longtitle") != null && Eval("services_longtitle").ToString() == "Google Ads Services" ? "<p class='h4'>" + Eval("services_sectiontitle") + "</p>" : "" %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```